# Linq get first or last element when List index out-of-range

Tags: c#, linq, list

With a List of articles, when one article is displayed I also display the next and previous article, I use the code below. I'm looking for a way to make this code leaner with Linq?

```
var article = allArticles.Where(x => x.UrlSlug == slug).FirstOrDefault();
int currentIndex = allArticles.IndexOf(article);

        if (currentIndex + 1 > allArticles.Count-1)
            article.Next = allArticles.ElementAt(0);
        else
            article.Next = allArticles.ElementAt(currentIndex + 1);

        if (currentIndex - 1 >= 0)
            article.Previous = allArticles.ElementAt(currentIndex - 1);
        else
            article.Previous = allArticles.Last();
return article;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think LINQ offers an "next or first" operation. Might as well use modulo:

```
article.Next = allArticles[(currentIndex + 1) % allArticles.Count];
article.Previous = allArticles[(currentIndex + allArticles.Count - 1) % allArticles.Count];
```

(The `+ allArticles.Count` in the second line is to correct for the mathematically wrong behavior of `%` when it is applied to negative numbers.)

Comment: LINQ does not have a "next" or "first" operation, it has an overload for the `Where` and the `Select` clause containing the index though. So with `.Where((content, index) => <some condition>)` and `Select((content, index) => <some member expression>)` it might be possible to achieve with LINQ.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh: `Where()` could work, but that would essentially require you to specify that the index must equal the expressions I have used above, and then you need to call `First()` to reduce the resulting `IEnumerable` to an actual element - so it would be a more complicated way of achieving the same element lookups. (You don't need `Select()` because there is no transformation of the elements.)

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with Aasmund Eldhuset answer.

Just make sure you don't get a null exception:

```
var article = allArticles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UrlSlug == slug);
var currentIndex = allArticles.IndexOf(article);

if (article == null) return;
article.Next = allArticles[(currentIndex + 1) % allArticles.Count];
article.Previous = allArticles[(currentIndex + allArticles.Count - 1) % allArticles.Count];
```